# How to disable battery saver in Opera 38.0?

Tags: opera

With the latest update to the Opera (version 38.0) a feature called “battery saver” was added.

Essentially it reduces browsing performance to preserve more battery power, which is great, *if* you do not work on a laptop all day and your performance reduces every 1-2 hours.

I didn’t find an option to turn it off permanently in the settings panel.
Is there a way to disable disable battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out accidentally today:

Focus the search bar and type `chrome://flags` (As the new Opera is built on the same engine as Chrome is) sure enough you will find the battery saver feature a little bit down the way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install latest version of Opera from any site (I used: https://filesmint.com/opera/)
2. Navigate to batery power saver icon (located below close button)
3. Now open Manage in setting
4. Inside main settings, locate battery saver menu and uncheck all 3 options.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is a battery saver icon right next to the search and address field. You'll see it when your laptop's power cable is unplugged. Click it and flip the switch on or off to activate or deactivate the battery saver feature.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, alas I am looking for a way to disable it permanently.